# Sphere Judge Palindrome

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve this: http://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/.I'm using Python and although it works right it seems to be too slow.I'm trying to find a way to improve performance.
Here's the code:

```
case=raw_input();
l=int(case)
cas=[]

for k in range(0,l,1):
  t=raw_input();
  cas.append(t)


con=False
print("")
for k in range(0,l,1):
var=int(cas[k])+1
var=str(var)
con= False
while con != True:


            n=int(var)

            i=len(var)
            j=-1


            for i in range(i,0,-1):
                j+=1
                if var[i-1]==var[j]:
                  pass
                else:
                  break


                if i==1:


                  print var
                  con=True
            n+=1
            var=str(n)
```

Any suggestions?Thanks in advance!

Comment: For starters, you should remove the empty lines from your code - it makes it fat less readable.

Comment: Please be careful how you paste this code in: currently, it is invalid due to spacing issues (lines after `for k in range(0,l,1):` are not indented).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to *find* palindrome. It consumes much of the time. Why not try to *build* it? Consider this:

1. For numbers with even length (like 3133):

1.1. Check if left half is lower or equals to right one (i.e 31 <= 33). If it so, then add 1 to left half (31+1 = 32).

1.2. Invert left half to build palindrome: 32->23

1.3. Get result: '32' + '23' = '3223'

2. For numbers with odd length you should do basically the same, but take special care of middle digit. I.e. in 809 left half (8) is lower than right (9), so you need to add 1 to middle digit and than build palindrome with left half: 818